# Find a Specific Repeated word

Tags: excel, vba

Sample data:

```
Column A                                 Column B(Expected Result)

Grand Theft Auto Auto Grand Theft        Auto
Bot Games Bot Games                      
Good Good Data                           Good
```

```
Sub Repeatwrd()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cellValueA As String
    Dim wordsA As Variant
    Dim wordIndex As Long
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim wordCount As Integer
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    
    
     Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     
    ' Get the last row of data in column A
    lastRow1 = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    ' Loop through each row of data in column A and compare with column B
    For i = 1 To lastRow1
        ' Get the values in columns A and B for the current row
        cellValueA = Cells(i, 1).Value
       
        
        ' Split the strings into words
        wordsA = Split(cellValueA, " ")
        

        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

         ' Loop through each word in the string
        For Each word In wordsA
            ' Count the number of occurrences of the word in the string
            wordCount = UBound(Split(cellValueA, word)) - LBound(Split(cellValueA, word))
            ' If the word occurs more than once, paste it in column C for the current row
            If wordCount > 1 Then
                If Not dict.exists(word) Then

                     Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & " " & word
                     dict.Add word, word

                End If
            End If
        Next word
        
    Next i
 
End Sub
```

i tried this i can able to identify the repeated words but i want specific repeated words mentioned in sample data words repeating one after another to be precise is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a simple function:

```
Function findDuplicateWord(s As String) As String
    Dim words() As String, i As Long
    words = Split(s, " ")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(words)
        If words(i) = words(i - 1) Then
            findDuplicateWord = words(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

The input is split into words. Now the function loops over all words, starting at the 2nd word (has index 1 as `split` return a 0 based array) and compare it with the word to the left. If found, it is returned.

If you need to compare case insensitive, just change the if-condition to

```
 If lCase(words(i)) = lCase(words(i - 1)) Then
```

Now you can use the function as UDF in your excel sheet: Put the formula `=findDuplicateWord(A2)` into cell B2 and copy down.

[image]